# problem with allocating memory for scipy ndarray

Tags: python, audio, scipy, out-of-memory, fft

I am trying to generate a `ndarray` of audio file frequencies using the `scipy.signal.stft()` function and it randomly crashes half the time. When it crashes it raises the Exception: `numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 257. MiB for an array with shape (32842, 513) and data type complex128`, how do I free up memory for such a large array? Or is there any other solution?

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFjxp.png)

Comment: What is your OS? Also, please copy your code as text and use proper formatting.

Comment: Why not slicing the file/array into several, smaller parts?

Comment: Please don't put code in images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question contains the reasons why.

Comment: Does that array shape look reasonable?